# Node.js MongoDB bulk batch docs from DB with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to extract a bulk set of docs from DB to process.

For testing I have 17 docs in db and using mongodb `2.2.31`.

This is the code I have

```
const query = collection.find({}).batchSize(10);
while(await query.hasNext()) {
  const docs = await query.toArray();
  console.log(await query.hasNext());
  log.info(docs.length);
}
```

When I run this, the process to runs forever logging out 17.

If I use the forEach method:

```
const query = collection.find({}).batchSize(10);
(await query.toArray()).forEach(function(data) {
  log.info(data._id.toString())
});
```

The process just runs 17 log lines with each doc _id.

I can't understand why .hasNext is always returning true.

--------------**UPDATE**---------------

So I have solved it by doing this, it's not perfect as it does a request for each doc, I really wanted to do a single request that returned 1000 docs from db.

I'm not sure this will work for me as I have a collection of 170million records.

```
const query = collection.find({});

let docs = [];
while (await query.hasNext()) {
  docs.push(await query.next());
  if (docs.length >= 1000) {
    await processDocs([...docs]);
    docs = [];
  }
}
processDocs(docs);
```

Comment: `toArray` and `hasNext` aren't really meant to be used together, and `toArray` always returns all documents in the cursor, regardless of batch size.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Odd it doesn't say that in docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hasNext/

So how would I get all 10 docs in one go then?

Comment: `hasNext` would typically be used with `nextObject`, not `toArray`. You can do your own client-side batching with `nextObject` or you can chain `.limit(10)` to your query to just get the first 10 results.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Probably better to stick to the published API methods when discussing. That would be [`next()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#next) ( not `nextObject` ). For the author, the other clear misunderstanding here seems to be about what `batchSize()` is for. As mentioned, you probably mean `.limit()` by the statements in your question. Which is essentially *"I expect 10 documents"*. The actual `batchSize` refers to how many documents the driver takes from the server at a time, and **not** a limit to the total results on the cursor.

Comment: @NeilLunn but by using limit that will only give me 10 records, I want all 17 but in batches of 10. In my actual code, I have millions of records and want to do them batches of 500s. If I use limit that won't iterate through them all.

Comment: Point is that "batches" by `batchSize` is not what you seem to think it is. You actually **do** want `limit()`. It's just that you do your "batches" in **separate requests**, either using `skip()` to go past `n` items, or doing a "range query" to find something like "greater than the last _id" or whatever unique ascending property in the last "batch" you had is. We're both telling you this because we do understand what you "really mean", even though you are getting the terminology wrong.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, chain a call to `.batchSize(1000)` and you'll have the efficiency you're looking for. That tells the driver to get 1000 docs at a time when it's actually fetching the docs from the server.